# Can I omit "the" in "the last time" when it introduces a time clause?

Tags: word-usage

Sentence 1a: **The** Last time I took my pulse, it was a bit fast.

Sentence 1b: Last time I took my pulse, it was a bit fast.

Sentence 2a: He looked much worried **the** last time I saw him.

Sentence 2b: He looked much worried last time I saw him.

Can I omit "the" in "the last time" when it introduces a time clause? which sentences sound natural to you?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I won't say for sure, but I don't think so, at least in formal speech or writing. Though you might get away with a phrase like "Last time, we ...".

Comment: Note: "He looked very worried..." not "much worried"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should point out, 2a and 2b both would be more natural to me if you used "very" instead of "much" -- "much worried" is not typical.

I don't claim to be representative of all speakers, but the use of "last time" to replace "the last time" sounds okay in both of these examples. I think it's much better in the first one than the second though--while I might expect to see 2b in casual speech, it would seem like swallowing or skipping over the "the" rather than something I know I would write.

Some web examples of the usage include a Facebook group called "[Last time I heard that, I laughed so hard I fell off my dinosaur!!!!!](https://www.facebook.com/pages/LAST-TIME-I-HEARD-THAT-I-LAUGHED-SO-HARD-I-FELL-OFF-MY-DINOSAUR-/178659064101)" (...for whatever that's worth as evidence) and the headline of this [Yahoo! news article](http://finance.yahoo.com/blogs/talking-numbers/last-time-this-happened--stocks-sold-off-hard-215406507.html). I think that's enough to show that it's recognized as legitimate by the average US English speaker. It also seems to come up a lot in song lyrics. But it seems most natural to me if it's at the beginning of a sentence.

In conclusion: when in doubt, use "the", and you won't be wrong. But I think you're right that you can probably omit it in many cases.